# How to import existing AWS resources like VPC using cdktf?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, terraform-cdk

I can import AWS resources using AWS CDK (python) like this

```
   # lookup existing VPC
    vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self,"vpc",vpc_id=vpcID,)
    
    #lookup existing Security group
    sec_group = ec2.SecurityGroup.from_lookup_by_id(self,'SG',sgID)
```

**I cannot find proper documentation or example of doing the same in terraform cdktf**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDKTF(Terraform) provides [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/cdktf/concepts/data-sources) to fetch information from resources created outside of Terraform, therefore you can use the `DataAwsVpc` method.