# cdktf, How to import resources from grafana (python)

Tags: import, grafana, terraform-cdk

I wish to import existing data sources from grafana.

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615477/how-to-import-existing-aws-resources-like-vpc-using-cdktf) and its answer is not satisfactory, as the resources have been created using cdktf, albeit in an earlier run.

How can I import using cdktf similar to the following terraform cli command:

```
terraform import grafana_data_source.by_integer_id {{datasource id}}
terraform import grafana_data_source.by_uid {{datasource uid}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `terraform import` command in your synthesized stack directory. The documentation about [moving a resource from one stack to another covers how the command can be constructed](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/examples-and-guides/refactoring#moving-resources-from-one-stack-to-another).